# table-layout:fixed not working on Kendo grid

Tags: css, kendo-ui, cross-browser, kendo-grid

I have a grid which is declared with column widths. basically like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikMvcApp1.Models.Product>()
.Name("acct_dtls")
          .HtmlAttributes(new{style="width:100%", @class="panel-body"})
          .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax().Read("Read", "Home"))
          .Pageable()
          .Sortable()
          .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                            columns.Bound(Agent => Agent.ProductID).Width(300).Encoded(false).Hidden(false).Groupable(false).IncludeInMenu(false).Sortable(false);
                            columns.Bound(Agent => Agent.ProductName).Width(100).Encoded(true).Hidden(false).Groupable(false).IncludeInMenu(true).Sortable(false);
                            })
          .Reorderable(r => r.Columns(true))
          .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
          .ColumnResizeHandleWidth(5)
          .ColumnMenu()
          .Filterable()
          .Scrollable()
        )
```

the problem is when it is rendered, the browser automatically adjust the columns widths just like responsive rendering. i have tried setting the table-layout property to "fixed" but still no working. Thanks for those who will share their knowledge

Answer (score 0):

The grid has the `table-layout: fixed` setting applied by default. The problem is that you have set the width of both columns to a value which is less than the total grid width. You should avoid setting the width of one of the columns so it can occupy the remaining space.

Comment: already fixed this issue in our project. were reading the column values from a database so we need to get just the exact value even if it doesnt fit the grid. thanks